# Why is GetHashCode important and where can we use it?

Tags: c#, hashcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overriden in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c)

Why is GetHashCode important and where can we use it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search reveals [the MSDN documentation for Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). Quoting:

> A hash code is a numeric value that is
>   used to identify an object during
>   equality testing. It can also serve as
>   an index for an object in a
>   collection.
>
> The GetHashCode method is suitable for
>   use in hashing algorithms and data
>   structures such as a hash table.

As an aside, if you're thinking of overriding it yourself, have a read through that link and also some of the many SO questions that have been asked on the topic.